# regex for capturing group that is only sometimes present

Tags: python, regex, grouping

I have a set of filenames like:

```
PATJVI_RNA_Tumor_8_3_63BJTAAXX.310_BUSTARD-2012-02-19.fq.gz
PATMIF_RNA_Tumor_CGTGAT_2_1_BC0NKBACXX.334_BUSTARD-2012-05-07.fq.gz
```

I would like to have a single regex (in python, fyi) that can capture each of the groups between the "_" characters.  However, note that in the second filename, there is a group that is present that is not present in the first filename.  Of course, one can use a string split, etc., but I would like to do this with a single regex.  The regex for the first filename is something like:

```
(\w+)_(\w+)_(\w+)_(\d)_(\d)_(\w+)\.(\d+)_(\S+)\.fq\.gz
```

And the second will be:

```
(\w+)_(\w+)_(\w+)_(\w+)_(\d)_(\d)_(\w+)\.(\d+)_(\S+)\.fq\.gz
```

I'd like the regex group to be empty when the optional group is present and contain the optional group when it is present (so that I can use it later to in constructing a new filename with \4).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make a group optional, you can add `?` after the desired group. Like this:
    (\w+)?

But your example has an underscore that should be optional as well. To deal with it, you can group it together with optional group.

```
((\w+)_)?
```

However this will add a new group to your match results. To avoid it, use a non-matching group:

```
(?:(\w+)_)?
```

The final result will look like this:

```
(\w+)_(\w+)_(\w+)_(?:(\w+)_)?(\d)_(\d)_(\w+)\.(\d+)_(\S+)\.fq\.gz
```

Comment: Don't you need to flip `(:?` around to `(?:`

Comment: Oops. Thanks alan. Fixed the post.

Comment: +1. Putting a capturing group inside a non-capturing group is a nice trick.